# How can I prevent a kotlin extension from being used on my objects?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

For special threading issue in my app I created an object with a `runOrQueue()` method which accepts a block. Here is a simplified version for illustrative purpose:

```
class SpecialThread {
    fun runOrQueue() {}
}
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to write code using this method, the IDE autocompletes first to a [Kotlin extension method named `run()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html), defined in the standard library:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R {…}
```

Here is a screen capture of the IDE autocompletion:

[image]

This is *especially dangerous* in the context of my app, since both `run` and `runOrQueue` would have similar results (both running a block of code), but the standard library version would crash in certain situations, wrapped properly in the `runOrQueue` method.

Is there any way I can explicitly *disable* the possibility of using the `run` extension on this particular object of my creation? In fact, reviewing the code I wrote myself, I've already mistakenly used `run` twice instead of the longer method name, and that is not good.

Comment: Since you find it dangerous and maybe it is, why don't you rename it to `queueOrRun()`?

Comment: Or `queueIfNotRun()` (this after Thomas Cook's suggestion)

Answer (score 3):

If you really really don't want to rename your method, and you're absolutely sure that you'll never use the `run` function...

You can actually exclude any method from autocompletion by clicking the intention action icon next to the suggestion:

[image: Exclude from completion]

In `Settings`, you can find this under `Editor -> General -> Auto Import`, and then `Exclude from import and completion`. For example, to exclude the built-in `run` function, you'd add this entry, either via the intention mentioned above, or manually:

[image: List of exclusions]

If you make this project scoped, the exclusion can be checked into VCS as well, you'll find it under `.idea/codeInsightSettings.xml`, which would have these corresponding contents to exclude `run`, pretty self explanatory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="JavaProjectCodeInsightSettings">
    <excluded-names>
      <name>kotlin.run</name>
    </excluded-names>
  </component>
</project>
```

Comment: Huh, didn't know that!

Answer (score 2):

While the comments to rename the method are worthy, I kept trying things to prevent the *wrong* code from compiling and managed to reach a compromise, which might be generalizable to other possible symbol clashes in the future.

First, in order to *confuse* the compiler, a very similar method is added to the object:

```
@Deprecated(level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR,
        message = "This is not the method you are looking for (waves hand)",
        replaceWith = ReplaceWith("runOrQueue()"))
fun <T, R> run(block: T.() -> R): R {
    TODO("Don't use this")
}
```

This is not exactly the same as the standard library `run()`, so when you start typing in the IDE you still get one suggestion for the standard library, and another for the object method. Fortunately, even if the autocomplete version is used, since there are two very similar `run()` methods, the compiler will complain about ambiguity.

In fact, after adding this method and rebuilding the source, the compiler caught two more instances of the mistake:

```
e: PasswordPresenter.kt: (181, 49): Using 'run(T.() -> R): R' is an error. This is not the method you are looking for (waves hand)
e: PasswordPresenter.kt: (181, 49): Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T, R> run(block: T.() -> R): R
Please specify it explicitly.

e: PasswordPresenter.kt: (258, 33): Using 'run(T.() -> R): R' is an error. This is not the method you are looking for (waves hand)
e: PasswordPresenter.kt: (258, 33): Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T, R> run(block: T.() -> R): R
Please specify it explicitly.
```

Not the prettiest in the world, but it comes close and gets the job done. Or as Sally Amaki would say, [fake it till you make it](https://twitter.com/sally_amaki/status/1039792429228908544).

Comment: clever workaround - terrible idea for production... 

You could literally apply this logic to any methods with similar names. Just make sure you call the correct methods.

Comment: The compiler isn't complaining about ambiguity, it's picking the member. It just "should" be defined as `fun <R> run(block: SpecialThread.() -> R)` (as `T` is fixed).

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid this isn't really possible as run is in the std library and is defined as an extension on any type:

```
/**
 * Calls the specified function [block] with `this` value as its receiver and returns its result.
 */
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline fun <T, R> T.run(block: T.() -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block()
}
```

Some options:

For the parts of your codebase where you don't want `run` to be used, write it in Java instead (as Kotlin and Java are completely interporable). This solution is not ideal.

Don't write `run` when you mean `runOrQueue`.

Write a custom lint extension to flag usages of `run` as a warning or an error:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint

EDIT:

Forpas gave another good solution to rename your function to `queueOrRun`. The problem with this is the OR, I imagine your method attempts to `run` and only falls back to `queue` if that is not possible, therefore changing the name of the function will make it less clear what it does.